# Is it possible to build a native android appliation (ndk) with only cmake?

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

i'm trying to write an application framework for android and linux/windows. Now my question is if it's possible to use only cmake for the compilation or do i need other ndk tools to create the final .apk file ? As far what i've read so far and what i know from cmake it must be possible but i find nothing on the web describing the build process. I hope someone can help me out here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, CMake alone is not sufficient for compile the project. CMake is just a *configuration* tool, which prepares scripts for build a project using some other *build* tool: Make, Visual Studio, etc. Those build tools call in order a compiler and a linker with proper arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You need C++ compiler for Android. It's not part of CMake, and the easiest (bit not the only) option is Android NDK. Note that you will need a compiler for Windows if your framework is intended to work there too.

But this will not produce an APK for you: this requires yet another tool, Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

So i need cmake to compile the native libraries for android and the windows/linux libraries and then the andoid sdk to create a .apk file ? android-ndk uses cmake to build native c/c++ code for android.

Comment: so i need gradle from the ndk to build the native-android librarires and create the .apk file ?